# How to use post method for gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a doubt in vb.net. When we pass hyperlink value to next page how to avoid showing the id in the next page URL.

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="id" DataTextField="id" HeaderText="ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="xxx.aspx?id={0}">
```

In next page it is showing the URL as `http:/xxx.aspx?id=01` which i don't want.

Comment: You're going to have to write some server side code and take the clicked on id and put it in a session variable.  Then the next page can get the id from the session.

Comment: Can u get me the code Mr.Rick. As i m beginner i m not getting.